# Tastypie: Order By Foreign Field?

Tags: django, tastypie

In Tastypie, you can sort an API response using order_by like:

```
www.yourbaseurl.com/api/v1/model/?order_by=field_to_sort_by
```

How do you order by a foreign field?

e.g. assume

```
Model Local (id, localfield, foreign)
Model Foreign (id, foreign_field)
```

I've tried:

```
www.yourbaseurl.com/api/v1/model/?order_by=foreign__foreign_field
```

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Yes. Add ordering = [foreign_model] into Meta for the Resource. Then, you should be able to call ?order_by=foreign__foreign_field.

Answer (score 2):

Did you included the foreign key in ordering list(in Meta)...!

```
class Meta:
    ordering = [<your foreign key field>]
```

However worth mentioning that it does not work same as filtering. I mean in filtering you also need to specify the specific field name in **Foreign key ModelResource**'s filtering option. However in case of ordering you do not need to do it, just specify the foreign key field name in **ordering** and then you can mention all field of it by **foreignkeyfield__fieldname**, It does not matter that **Foreign key ModelResource** have that field in ordering list or not.

Answer (score -2):

You can create a foreign key reference in your resource like this

```
class LocalResource(Local):
    foreign = fields.ForeignKey(LocalResource, full=True)

    class Meta:
```

Then in your api call you can do the following.

```
www.yourbaseurl.com/api/v1/model/?order_by=foreign__field=value
```

Comment: And what should be `value`? it didn't work here, first of all I assume LocalResource should be replaced with ForeignResource (or whatever it's called) and second of all, fields.ForeignKey needs to called like  this: `fields.ForeignKey(ForeignResource, 'label', full = True)`. It didn't work anyway. Says: `{"error":"No matching 'foreign__field' field for ordering on."}` though I added `'foreign__field'` and `'foreign'` to `ordering` in `Meta` class. @sirFunkenstine

Comment: Thats not even a semantically correct URI! I don't see how that could work?

Comment: To follow up ;-
?order_by=foreign__field=value
What here is the key and what is the value?. If this works, perhaps it should be raised as a bug, because it SHOULDNT work.